# I wish this animation would stay on the page for a few seconds and then fade away

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

```
@keyframes appear {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes appearFromTop {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-500px);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

    30% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    50% {
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-500px);
        border-radius: 50px;
    }
}

.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 800px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transition: background-color 0.25s 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.box--from-top {
    animation: appearFromTop 5s 0.5s both;
}
```

I wish this animation would stay on the page for a few seconds and then fade away. So my question is: How can I do that? I think I tried everything. animation-delay is not working, animation-play-state is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add "no-op" in the animation process: i.e., make the opacity be at 1 from the 10% to 90% of the animation timeline.

For the length of 5 second, it would mean that 80% of 5 seconds (that's 4 seconds) the element stays on full opacity, 0.5s to fade in and 0.5s to fade out.

```css
box{
  animation: 5s linear 0s 1 normal fade-in-out;
  opacity: 0;

}

@keyframes fade-in-out{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  10% {opacity: 1}
  90% {opacity: 1}
  100% {opacity: 0}
}
```

```html
<box> Hello, world! </box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? You can make a long animation and only animate in between certain percentage values.

For example:
A 5 second animation where a fade-in happens between 0-20% and a fade-out between 80-100% would mean it fades in for 1 second, remains on screen for 3, fades out for 1 second again.

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.box--from-top {
    animation: inOut 5s;
}

@keyframes inOut {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    20% {
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80% {
        transform: translateY(50px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box box--from-top"></div>
```

It'd also be possible to have a separate fade-in and fade-out animations CSS animation with a little bit of javascript do the trick for you. This can be more flexible in general.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
setTimeout(function(){
  box.classList.remove('fadein');
  box.classList.add('fadeout');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.fadein {
    animation: fadein 1s;
}

.fadeout {
    animation: fadeout 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        top: -60px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        top: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box fadein"></div>
```